# send JMX data to remote server (JMX forwarder?)

Tags: java, jmx, splunk

Is there a existing setting/agent/code available that will allow me to collect and **easily forward JMX data to a remote server:port**?

```
java -DjmxForwardAddr=x.x.x.x -DjmxForwardPort=12345 ... ?
```

Context:
I'm using Splunk for enterprise data search/reporting, and would like to configure it with a JMX listener (the easy part) and setup up all JVMs somehow to just **deliver that data as JSON/XML/etc to Splunk**.

I'm looking for a **"push" approach**, rather than "pull" method where I allocate and manage thousands of ports and poll them.

We have lots of apps, and I'd like a nice way of just tweaking the startup to enable this.

Java and JMX aren't things I have a lot of expertise with, so maybe I'm searching for the wrong terms/asking the wrong questions.  I'm open to any better ways of approaching this, too.

**Edit 2016/09/01:**

I have been unable to find anything small and reliable to do this.  Through research, I also became concerned about this approach (running as java agent) as any misbehavior could negatively impact the parent program.

Taking an external approach, I though [jmxtrans](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans) would fit the bill. It worked somewhat, but would have still required writing a custom Output Writer to clean up the output for Splunk.

Currently, I am moving forward with a Splunk-supplied [solution](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/2647/) that polls a configurable list of targets and ingests that data.  Can't always get what you want (unless you write it yourself...)

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issues with zabbix. It used to read (pull) JMX data from Java application opening huge number of ports. Here the problem was that in the production environment, there is no guarantee if those ports will be behind firewall or not. To solve that, we used [Jolokia](https://jolokia.org). Jolokia runs as another application (if you are using tomcat etc) along with your application. Or if your application is a plain vanilla Java application, it can be used as a jar in the class path (i.e. it's really super simple to integrate with existing Java applications). It exposes JMX data over HTTP (JSON). So, if Splunk has any plugin which can read data over HTTP you will be good to go.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - it looks very handy.  although with it, I would have to also implement a retrieval system to get the data.  I have bookmarked Jolokia as a future research topic in case I get too dissatisfied with the vendor-provided solution.

Comment: For zabbix, I have used a third party gateway to do that job. https://bitbucket.org/ryanrupp/zabbix-java-gateway/wiki/Home. Not sure if something similar is there for Splunk as well.

Answer (score 0):

JMX API provide a way to create MBeans that generate notifications.

Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/NotificationEmitter.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/NotificationBroadcaster.html

Comment: that does look helpful, but I was looking for something already built.

Comment: Do you mean something like appdynamics?

Comment: possibly, though I'm not familiar with that.  CA APM (wily/introscope) has this functionality, in which it sends the metrics to a central server.

Answer (score 0):

With ElasticStack you can use MetricBeats to locally poll your JMX via Jolokia and then the NetricBeat can forward to a Logstash endpoint.  I would think you could configure to forward to Splunk similarly.  In this way, the polling configutation can be controlled locally with the Metricbeat configuration rather than remotely in the Splunk server.  Might work better depending on how admin access and configuration is controlled at the central log collector.